# where do i modify 'signin-google' in owin security for google redirect url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, google-oauth-.net-client

Im working on asp mvc 5 with google oauth login, 
I followed a tutorial installing owin security and set the google redirect url to be localhost/myapp/signin-google,

my question is where can i change the localhost/myapp/signin-google to be something else like localhost/myapp/mycallback ?

i tried change is to be localhost/myapp/signup/ExternalLoginCallback which the actual action, but it didnt work, is 'signin-google' hardcoded in owin security??

Comment: Did you try to change `CallbackPath` in `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adem is right. Here is how you change it:

```
var options = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "Your Client ID",
    ClientSecret = "Your Client Secret",
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/myapp/mycallback")
};
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options);
```

Please see this [link](http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/) for more details.

Comment: ta ,  this is a text length fixer

Comment: Hello! I would like to ask how do I have to set the CallbackPath when I am working in localhost? It always return me to the page that I have login but I want to return at the home page. Thank you

Comment: With callbackpath you are setting only the relative path. The domain stays the same. So please add the relative path to your home page to CallbackPath variable.